# ConTeXt: Full text justification using \definefont

Tags: context, justification, frame

## Background

Looking to make speech bubbles autofit the text using ConTeXt LMTX.

## Problem

The right padding on the framed text changes depending on whether the macro for `\definefont` is used. In the output (below), both frames should be fully justified. Switching the font breaks full justification.

## Code

Sample code:

```tex
\definefont       [TextFontEmoji] [OpenSansEmoji]
\definefontfamily [TextFont] [rm] [LibreBaskerville] 
\setupbodyfont    [TextFont]

\starttext
  \startframedtext
    \TextFontEmoji
    \input ward
  \stopframedtext

  \startframedtext
    \input ward 
  \stopframedtext
\stoptext
```

The above code produces:

[image: Text Frame Padding]

## Question

How do you switch the font while maintaining justification within a `\framedtext` environment?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2022/105402.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OTF version of OpenSansEmoji cannot be justified with ConTeXt.

https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji

Completely remove the OTF version from the system and use the TTF version instead. This involves removing the `luametatex-cache` directory and rebuilding the font cache.

The following works as expected to produce left and right speech bubbles that include an emoji:

```tex
\definefont [TextFontEmoji] [OpenSansEmoji]

\startuseMPgraphic{TextBubble}{side}
  z1 = (0, 0) ;
  z2 = (OverlayWidth, 0) ;
  z3 = (OverlayWidth, OverlayHeight) ;
  z4 = (0, OverlayHeight) ;

  offset := 1 ;
  tail := 1 ;

  % Flip the tail's location and direction.
  if \MPvar{side} = 1:
    offset := 5 ;
    tail := -1 ;
  fi

  (offset/6)[x1,x2] = x8 + .25cm * tail = x7 + .25cm = x9 - .25cm ;
  y7 =  0cm ;
  y8 = -.5cm ;
  y9 =  0cm ;

  path p ;
  p = (z1--z7--z8--z9--z2--z3--z4--cycle) cornered .25cm ;
  draw p withpen pencircle scaled 0.75 ;

  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineframedtext[TextBubbleFrame][
  style=TextFontEmoji,
  frame=off,
  width=.618\textwidth,
  autowidth=force,
  offset=.75em,
  after={\blank[2*big]},
]

% Receive text (left-facing).
\defineoverlay[TextBubbleRxOverlay][\useMPgraphic{TextBubble}{side=0}]
\defineframedtext[TextBubbleRxFrame][TextBubbleFrame][
  background=TextBubbleRxOverlay,
  location=left,
]

% Send text (right-facing).
\defineoverlay[TextBubbleTxOverlay][\useMPgraphic{TextBubble}{side=1}]
\defineframedtext[TextBubbleTxFrame][TextBubbleFrame][
  background=TextBubbleTxOverlay,
  location=right,
]

\definestartstop[bubblerx][
  before={\startnarrower\startTextBubbleRxFrame},
  after={\stopTextBubbleRxFrame\stopnarrower},
]

\definestartstop[bubbletx][
  before={\startnarrower\startTextBubbleTxFrame},
  after={\stopTextBubbleTxFrame\stopnarrower},
]

\starttext
  \startbubblerx
    Welcome to the future, human !  \input zapf
  \stopbubblerx

  \startbubbletx
    Welcome to the future, human !  \input zapf
  \stopbubbletx
\stoptext
```